# Haskell printing [[[Char]]] to IO

Tags: haskell, io, system.printing

Hi I have small problem with printing `[[[Char]]]` using IO.

I have a `[[[Char]]]` list - in another words `[[String]]`

I would like to print them like

```
FirstStringOfFirstListOfStrings
SecondStringOfFirstListOfStrings
.
.
.
LastStringOffFirstListofStrings
(some gap anything empty line "----" string anything)
FirstStringOfSecondsListOfStrings
```

In another words I don't want the `[String]` to be printed one under another (one row break at least or some line filled with `------` for example)

```
mapM_ (mapM_ print)
```

My idea was to compose the `(mapM_ print)` function with another but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Edit: Here's an example, as requested

data to print: `[["abc","cde","efg"],["hjk","mno","prs"],["stu","wxy","zzz"]]`

while using `mapM_ (mapM_ print)` it prints like

```
abc
cde
efg
hjk
mno
prs
stu
wxy
zzz
```

But I would like it to be printed like this:

```
abc
cde
efg

hjk
mno
prs

stu
why
zzz
```

They can be separated by an empty line or some string.

Comment: You could help us by showing example input and output.  You should also consider using a pure function to define the final string(s) to output before invoking IO.

Comment: as you requested i put an example of code 

well that [[String]] Board is an result of big nondeterministic algoritm making it pure would be quite hard

i think there is a way to do it but monad types restrits me hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with types. What you have is `[[String]]` and what you want is `[[IO ()]]` i.e each `String` gets converted to a `IO ()` action (to print it). Lets try to achieve this:

```
strToPrint :: [[String]] -> [[IO ()]]
strToPrint strs = map (map putStrLn) strs
```

Now we want `[[IO ()]]` to flatten to get `[IO ()]` where we insert the desired line break print action as well while flattening the list.

```
flattenActions :: [[IO ()]] -> [IO ()]
flattenActions actions = concat $ intersperse [(putStrLn "")]  actions
```

Now we can execute these `[IO ()]` action one by one using `sequence_`. It seems we can combine all these functions into one function using functional composition and hence we get

```
printStrings :: [[String]] -> IO ()
printStrings  = sequence_ . flattenActions . strToPrint
```

And use it like:

```
main = printStrings [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]
```

You can then look for making this more generic and refactor it accordingly.

Comment: Since I'm a nitpicker, I'll point out that `(concat .) . intersperse == intercalate`, except that the latter is (I think) liable to be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

With your example the code, for any separator 'sep' is then:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

let x = [["abc","cde","efg"],["hjk","mno","prs"],["stu","wxy","zzz"]]

p sep = putStr . unlines . intercalate sep

main = do
    p "" x
    p "---" x
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that mapM_ takes a function that returns a monadic action as its parameter. That action can be
composed using the normal monadic operations.

So in your code sample you have:

```
printStrings :: [[String]] -> IO ()
printStrings = mapM_ (mapM_ putStrLn)
```

Whereas you would like to have:

```
printStrings :: [[String]] -> IO ()
printStrings = mapM_ (\xs -> (mapM_ putStrLn) xs >> putStrLn ""))
```

So what we do is to replace the inner `mapM_ putStrLn` with a function:
 `\xs -> mapM_ (putStrLn xs >> putStrLn "")` that also prints out the separator.